# Using wildcard subdomain on specific directory

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress, wildcard-subdomain

I am setting up an existing wordpress install to use multisite.  I have successfully set up the network and since it was an existing install it uses subdomains (which I wanted anyways).

I have created a new site/subdomain on my network so it would look something like this example.domain.com

The issue I am running into is getting wildcard subdomains setup on my hosting provider BlueHost.

I am hosting multiple domains so when I setup a wildcard it always points to the root or original ip address.

I need it to point to a specific directory of the root so it uses the correct wordpress install.  root/specific-directory

Is there a way to achieve this?  I am not too familiar with a and cname issues.  If there is a way to achieve it by writing in the htaccess that would be okay too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I am hosting multiple domains so when I setup a wildcard it always points to the root

I'm assuming you meant that you get the same content for `example.domain.com` as if you were visiting `www.domain.com`. This can surely be handled through `htaccess` rewrite rules.

If a sub-domain named `subsite` was to be served out of `${DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subsite` directory, you would add the following rules to your `.htaccess` placed at your web root `/` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subsite\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subsite [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subsite/$1 [L]
```

If there are several mutisite subdomains that need redirection, use the following dynamic rules instead:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/([^/]+).*?::\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

You would also need to add `ServerAlias *.domain.com` to your `<VirtualHost>` configuration in Apache's `httpd.conf` file.

---

It seems BlueHost doesn't take up any requests to modify `httpd.conf` directly for you. But, they do provide a way to setup a *wildcard subdomain* from their Control Panel.

Take a look at [How to Set Up a WordPress MultiSite in Bluehost](http://www.markleobongcasan.com/blog/how-to-set-up-a-wordpress-multisite-in-bluehost-dealing-with-multisite-installation-problem-in-bluehost/). The last section outlines the process with screen shots. You also need to enable theme per site for your subdomains.

[image: Wildcard Subdomain]

Comment: Do I create a wildcard subdomain a or cname record?  When I create a name record it points to the root, so I am assuming that's what I need to make your rewrite rules work?

Comment: Both `A` or `CNAME` should work. You would also need to add `ServerAlias *.domain.com` to your Apache's `<VirtualHost>` configuration.

Comment: I am using BlueHost and this is the support it provided on such topic: **We do not support Virtual directories (in the traditional sense). These are setup using a VirtualHost container in the httpd.conf file for Apache. We do not provide support for any client's requests for modifying the httpd.conf. Therefore, it is not a possibility on our servers. You can, however, emulate a "Virtual Directory" build using mod_rewrite to rewrite input to a script in another location. See mod_rewrite tutorial for more tips how to use it.**

Comment: On BlueHost you can do it from Control Panel. Take a look at [How to Set Up a WordPress MultiSite in Bluehost](http://www.markleobongcasan.com/blog/how-to-set-up-a-wordpress-multisite-in-bluehost-dealing-with-multisite-installation-problem-in-bluehost/). The last section outlines the process with screenshots.

Comment: Okay so currently I am not using the redirect as it doesn't seem to be needed.  I followed those steps at the end.  Now when I pull up a http://ksu.zoofrog.com it's just a blank white page.  I've disabled all plugins to see if it was causing a conflict but still the same result.  The original site still works though http://zoofrog.com

Comment: It seems the BlueHost cpanel provides the similar functionality that you are trying to achieve through htaccess. Can you try creating a `ksu` domain mapped to `/public_html/ksu` directory? Does your wp site at `/public_html/ksu` then work without the htaccess rules?

Comment: If not, create the wildcard domain `*` and make sure you've mapped it to `/public_html` instead of `/public_html/wildcard`. Try again and see if you find something in error logs if it doesn't work.

Comment: Currently I have the wildcard domain * mapped to /public_html/zoofrog/ as the website tutorial you provided said to do.  Then I used WordPress MU to create my subdomain **ksu.zoofrog.com** and that's when I get the blank white webpage.  The .htaccess rules I used were also from the tutorial you provided.

Comment: My problem was I didn't enable the theme on the subdomain.  Thank you for your knowledge.  Points awarded for your continuing support.  Please put that link in your answer so other people don't have problems like me!  Also let them know to enable the theme per site.

Comment: @AnthonyRusso Thanks for suggesting. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

1- You can add your subdomain as an addon domain and it can have a separate subdirectory as you want. 
2- Another way to achieve this is using another host for subdomians. On the second host you set up your subdomains and point your subdomains from your main host to subdomains on the secondary host.