# Subdomain point to directory that inside specific directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, subdomain

i get the source code from [Stackoverflow-Using wildcard subdomain on specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19432591/using-wildcard-subdomain-on-specific-directory)

original code:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/([^/]+).*?::\1
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [L]
```

it's work properly, but the code above is pointing the directory from root. i want all subdomain point to the directory which is in my "portfolio" directory, so i try modify myself the code

after modify(added "/portfolio"):

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.mlaxproject\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/([^/]+).*?::\1
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /portfolio/%1/$1 [L]
```

but it give me "500 -Internal Server Error" ... why? can anybody correct my code?

Thank and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `/portfolio` to your `RewriteCond` too.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)([^.]+)\.mlaxproject\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::%1 !^/portfolio/([^/]+).*?::\1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /portfolio/%1/$1 [L]
```

Comment: sorry for late replay^^ thx Ravi Thapliyal! you really solve my proble,!

Comment: I'm glad this helped. Did you notice the question you started with points to my answer again? :)